# Best way to identify a mysql changed "group by" field value in a statement fetch in php?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a sql query in my php:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orderTaken WHERE orderStatus='10' GROUP BY orderId ORDER BY orderTakenTime DESC";
```

Now, I have to echo back several HTML tables based on different orderIds, so basically if the orderId is changed, a new HTML table will be created and contains the info of all the things under this orderId. This is what I have done(kinda pseudocode, please ignore the syntax error. My real code is far more complicated but the idea is here: set an oldOrderId and check it with the newly fetched orderId and see if the orderId is changed):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orderTaken WHERE orderStatus='10' GROUP BY orderId ORDER BY orderTakenTime DESC";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
for ($i = 0; $i<$count + 1; $i++ ){
    if ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $orderId = $row["orderId"];
        $2ndField = $row["2ndField"];
        $3rdField = $row["3rdField"];
        ...
        // check if $oldOrderId is set
        if (isset($oldOrderId)){
            // and compare, if the orderId changes, end the table and create a new one
            if ($oldOrderId != $orderId){
                echo "</table><br>";
                echo "<table><tr><th>...</th></tr>";
                ...
                //UPDATE old orderId
                $oldOrderId = $orderId;
            // if orderId doesn't change, continue echo table content
            } else {
                echo "<table><tr><td>...</td></tr>";
            }
        // if the oldOrderId is not set, it means this is the first fetched row, and the very first table will be created
        } else {
            echo "<table><tr><th>...</th></tr>";
            ...
            echo "<table><tr><td>...</td></tr>";
            ...
            //SET oldOrderId
            $oldOrderId = $orderId;
        }
    }
    if ($i == $count) {
        //End the last table
        echo "</table><br>";
    }
}
```

The code can run but will be buggy sometimes and I don't think this is a smart way to identify it. Is there any existed method like 
    $row = $stmt->fetch().prev()
to get the last row's orderId's value? Or if there's any better way to perform it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is it "Buggy sometimes"?

Comment: I didn't figure it out either... sometimes the table I echoed back is wrong or some information that should be contained in the table is missing. The reason should be that the logic of my own code inside of these blocks is wrong. But I'm just asking if there's a better way to check if this value changes so maybe it will help me write the right echo-back-table logic as well :D

Comment: If you are using `GROUP BY` in your query, then you're probably going to want some sort of "group function" in your `SELECT` (like `SUM()`, `COUNT()`, `GROUP_CONCAT()`, etc.).  When you add `GROUP BY orderId`, your result will have *one row* per `orderId`, and with `SELECT *`, all you're gonna get for the other fields is *one* of the many values that are in the table.  Your storing of and checking `$oldOrderId` only works *without* the `GROUP BY orderId`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat After I appreciated the answer I was about to say thanks to the comments and then just realized you are the same person who answered my question lol! Thanks again I definitely will learn more about those "group function". Yea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your inclusion of `GROUP BY orderId` in your query.  What this does is give you *one row* per each `orderId` in your table.

Since you are using `SELECT *`, then all you are getting back is one row for each `orderId` and *one* of the other values in the table for each of the other fields.

When using `GROUP BY`, you usually want to add a "group function" - like `SUM()`, `COUNT()`, `GROUP_CONCAT()`, etc. - to your query.

Your approach with the `$oldOrderId` is fine and could work if you change your query to something like:

```
SELECT * FROM orderTaken
WHERE orderStatus='10'
ORDER BY orderID DESC, orderTakenTime DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Rocket! Wow you are absolutely right I misunderstood how group by works. I thought that could just group the entries by the same orderId few by few but I just checked my query in phpmyadmin and it IS as you said, it only gives me ONE per row instead of few by few... And your code is exactly what I want for my performance with my original $oldOrderId approach. They work now! Thank you! Learned from you

Comment: Glad I could help :-)